# How to integrate Angular theme in Node + mysql+ express

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, node.js, express

I am new to node, angular and express.. Please **help** me if u can.

I have created REST API using node+express+mysql already,
Now I have to **integrate** this [blur-admin](https://akveo.github.io/blur-admin/) theme into existing project ..
After following instructions i am able to run theme with gulp separately but not know how to connect it with mysql or existing project.

I use `nodemon SERVER` to run existing project

**SERVER.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var mysql   = require("mysql");
var bodyParser  = require("body-parser");
var md5 = require('md5');
var rest = require("./REST.js");
var app  = express();

var helmet = require('helmet');
app.use(helmet());

app.disable('x-powered-by');

function REST(){
    var self = this;
    self.connectMysql();
};

REST.prototype.connectMysql = function() {
    var self = this;
    var pool      =    mysql.createPool({
        connectionLimit : 100,
        host     : 'localhost',
        user     : 'root',
        password : 'phpmyadmin',
        database : 'myApp',
        debug    :  false
    });
    pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){
        if(err) {
          self.stop(err);
        } else {
          self.configureExpress(connection);
        }
    });
}

REST.prototype.configureExpress = function(connection) {
      var self = this;
      app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
      app.use(bodyParser.json());
      var router = express.Router();
      app.use('/api', router);
      var rest_router = new rest(router,connection,md5);
      self.startServer();
}

REST.prototype.startServer = function() {
      app.listen(3000,function(){
          console.log("All right ! I am alive at Port 3000.");
      });
}

REST.prototype.stop = function(err) {
    console.log("ISSUE WITH MYSQL n" + err);
    process.exit(1);
}

new REST();
```

Use `gulp serve` to run blur-admin theme

**gulpfile.js**

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var wrench = require('wrench');

/**
 *  This will load all js or coffee files in the gulp directory
 *  in order to load all gulp tasks
 */
wrench.readdirSyncRecursive('./gulp').filter(function(file) {
  return (/\.(js|coffee)$/i).test(file);
}).map(function(file) {
  require('./gulp/' + file);
});


/**
 *  Default task clean temporaries directories and launch the
 *  main optimization build task
 */
gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function () {
  gulp.start('build');
});
```

NOW i don't know how to **merge** them both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While searching on Internet I found the hint on youtube **MEAN stack** tutorial video.
After that I followed these steps:

Moved angular js "blur-admin" theme to public folder of express
executed command

```
 gulp serve
```

to run client side 
and on express folder executed command

```
nodemon SERVER
```

To run server side on **deferent port**.
Than made REST **API** on express as required.
Used this API on client side theme controller as

```
$http.get('http://192.168.1.96:4000/api/apiname').
      success(function(data) {
       //code here
      });
```